# Using for loops to create a bar graph

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

**CAN ONLY USE LOOPS & IF/ELSE Statements**

So for my assignment I'm given this: Write a program with for loops that asks the user to enter today’s sales for five stores. The program should then display a bar graph comparing each store’s sales. Create each bar in the bar graph by displaying a row of asterisks. Each asterisk should represent $100 of sales.

So it should like:

Store 1: *****

Store 2: ***

Store 3: *******

etc.

I have most of it written up and everything displays properly except for my asterisks. I can't seem to get them to display. Also, I've searched around and there are answers to this, but all of them include arrays and we aren't allowed to use them in this exercise. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        int sales = 0, sale = 0; //Identfy Variables

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                cout << "Enter today's sales for Store " << i << ":" << endl;
                cin >> sale;
                sales += sale;
                sales /= 100; //in a similar manner to +=, /= can be used for division.
        }

        cout << "SALES BAR CHART:" << endl;
        cout << "Each * = $100" << endl;

                for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
                        cout << "Store " << x << ": ";
                        for (int s = 0; s < sales; s++) cout << "*";
                        cout << endl;
                }

         return 0;
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of cleaning up your code. An important part of programming is good code style, which makes code easier for people (especially others) to read. http://pastebin.com/t2rqxh3D

Comment: Really appreciate that, thank you!

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference usually, but I like to indent with tabs (instead of spaces) so that backspacing accidental indentations is quicker. Also, you save a lot of vertical space (which on widescreen monitors is more valuable than horizontal space) by putting the beginning of a block `{` on the same line as `for`, `if`, etc.

The holy war between spaces and tabs has been around for a while: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/57/109689

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string star = "";   
    int sale;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter today's sales for Store " << i << ":" << endl;
        cin >> sale;
        star += "Store " + to_string(i) + string(":");
        for(int j= 0; j<sale/100; j++) {
            star += "*";
        }    
        star += "\n";
    }
    cout<<star;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just give code without explaining what it does. It may be obvious to you, but for completeness, don't just chuck in a block of code and call it a day

Comment: This outputted I think all thousand of my asterisk. Each value should be divided by 100. I'm not familiar with the 'string' part though.

Comment: @HOAX I've divided the sale/100 in the for loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: @DhiwaTdG Alright for second initialization divided the sale by 100. It works, I feel like this might be too advanced for my class. Not one of my peers would be able to make this I feel.

Comment: I understand it. May be I'll come up with an alternative solution which is simpler. Please accept the answer if it is right.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG would appreciate it if you came up with an alternative that doesn't use string manipulation or arrays. We just haven't got to that and my professor would know it's above my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you do not store the data for each store individually. You have one variable called `sales`, which stores the sales of only the *last* store the end-user entered. All numbers the user enters before that get written over.

Since you have five stores, `sales` needs to be an array of five items:

```
int sales[5], total = 0;
```

Change your `for` loop to iterate 0 through 4, inclusive. Print `(i+1)` to end-users to stay one-based. Read sales numbers into `sales[i]` array element, then use it in the second loop to print your bar graph:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    cout << "Enter today's sales for Store " << (i+1) << ":" << endl;
    cin >> sales[i];
    sales[i] /= 100;
    total += sales[i];
}
...
// Now print your bar graph using a loop on i, and sales[i]
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use arrays in this unfortunately.

Comment: @HOAX How are you supposed to store the numbers the end-user enters, before displaying the bar graph?

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use arrays (which is preposterous), you can just use 5 different variables: `sales1`...`sales5`. This *terrible* code style and shouldn't be done (it's exactly what arrays are for), but it'll get the job done.

Comment: `int sale1, sale2, sale3, sale4, sale5`;` ? :{

Comment: @AMomchilov I'm going to email my professor. We just haven't learned about them yet so I assume I can't use them. Using the different variables that you mentioned would get really sloppy right?

Comment: Well the whole point of an array is the the number called the *index* can be a variable that's unknown at compile time (at the time you've written your program, before you've run it). You can use a for loop and iterate over the elements of an array. However, you cannot do this with hardcoded variable names, you'd have to repeat the same step for `step1`, then for `step2`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is missing a definition of s:

`for (int s; s < sales; s++)`

should be:

`for (int s = 0; s < sales; s++)`

Without this explicit initialization, a variable `s` is declared, and memory is allocated for it, but its value remains whatever was left in memory from the last time that address was used. It's likely that this left over data was equivalent to an integer larger than `sales`, and thus your `for` loop wouldn't run, not even once.

As @dasblinkenlight mentioned, you have a singular variable that stores the "sales" of every store. Each store needs a separate variable, since each store is going to sell a different amount.

Comment: Alright this caused to make the asterisks appear, but they all have 50 asterisk that pop up for each store regardless of the amount I enter.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answers, I just want to add two options that would make printing the `*`'s easier:

1. using [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n):

   ```
   std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>(cout), sales, '*');
   cout << endl;
   ```
2. using [`std::string`'s constructor overload (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

   ```
   cout << std::string(sales, '*') << endl;
   ```

Comment: This is a bit advanced for a beginner to use. I wouldn't suggest they use magic-behind-the-scenes-smoke-and-mirrors type code like this until they understand what's going on

Comment: You're right, actually the whole code would be something different with this style :) But, it might serve for further reference.

Comment: #2 should be simple enough for anyone to understand, and it would be my preference.